# Авторизация на Glassfish+JDBCReal - как добавить логирование входа\выхода

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, auth

Существует проект в котором поднята и работает авторизация на `Glassfish+JDBCRealm`.
Сейчас появилась необходимость добавить ведение логов успешных\не успешных попыток входа в систему.
Насколько я понимаю навешать фильтр на `j_security_check` не представляется возможным.

Другой вариант который я рассматриваю - `extend  com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm`.
В нем переписать метод `isUserValid`.

Есть ли другие варианты решения данной проблемы. И какие могут быть проблемы при подмене класса в `Glassfish` на собственный?
На другой способ авторизации возможности перейти нет.